# Vuetify autocomplete not showing dynamic results without focusing out and then focusing in

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using **Vue 3** and **Vuetify 3** and I am trying to use `<v-autocomplete />` to return data from an API.

### Code:

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model:search="search"
  @input="querySelections"
  :loading="loading"
  :items="products"
  item-title="name"
  item-value="id"
  hide-no-data
  hide-details
></v-autocomplete>
```

### Problem is:

I have to type something and focus out then focus in again to see the results.

### What I have tried:

I have tried to use watcher and tried to use return-json from Vuetify 2 but still nothing explains that strange behavior.

Comment: The [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#asynchronous-items) includes an example of fetching results asynchronously.  Try starting with the example code and modifying to suit your needs.  If there's something specific you need help with, post enough code that others can understand the problem.  The template code alone does not show how your v-autocomplete works